# Set enviroment variable with having space mac

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables

I want to set an environment variable that has space in it. it is a path to a folder and the folder name is:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10
```

I edit `.bash_profile` and add the following line to it:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10
```

and I get the result

> ```
> -bash: export: `Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10': not a valid identifier
> ```

what should I do?

Comment: thank you ,but it doesn't work and I change it to /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10 it works.

Comment: Use quotes around the value, or, yes, escape the space...

Answer (score 11):

You can do it either this

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10
```

way or this

```
export GRADLE_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10"
```

**Important**

Having taken so much pain in exporting the variable correctly, always make sure that you double quote the variable when you reference it in shell ie  do:

```
"$GRADLE_HOME"
```

and not

```
$GRADLE_HOME
```

Example  :

```
ls $GRADLE_HOME
```

will produce unexpected results.

Comment: Also, if you use this variable at the command line (or in a shell script), you *must* put the variable reference in double-quotes (e.g. `cd "$GRADLE_HOME"`) or it'll be split into multiple arguments. No, there's no simpler way to do it; just get in the habit of double-quoting variable references in your scripts, or they *will* break.